# Seeing a map is Holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Consider the Khaler manifold $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$, and the function $\Psi^{A}([z_0,...,z_n])=[z_0,e^{iA}z_1,...,e^{niA}z_n]$ for $A\in S^1$.

Now I would like to check wether or not this is an holomorphic funciton, i.e., that $d\Psi^A \circ J = J\circ d\Psi^A$.

I belive this is going to be true, however to check it , the only way I am seeing that I can prove this is by actually computing the differential in local coordinates and check it here. This seems doable but I was wondering if there would be a more clever way to do this , i.e., without realying on much computations ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give me a definition of algebraic or a reference where I can look it up ? @user10354138

Comment: 1. Probably the multiplier should be $e^{iA}$ (in $S^{1}$) for $A$ _real_. ;)  2. In each affine coordinate chart, the stated mapping is _linear_.